# Can I use multiple copies of a Windows Forms Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Say, if I were using a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx) that I want to use at multiple (say three) places on a form. I could use three different labels but it would be much simpler if I could just use copies of one label. This latter approach would allow me to change properties related to the labels at one place, while with the former approach I'd have to go to each of the three labels to change their properties. Hopefully, my question is clear.

Is there a way to use multiple copies of the same Windows Forms Control?

Comment: No, just think, every label has its position. If the three labels share the same properties how do you position them differently on the form? They are `instances` of the same class Label and every one has its own life with its properties unique to each one.

Comment: If you want to make manipulation of multiple controls easier you could insert like controls into a collection then apply the changes to the whole list, so that they are exact. The other approach is that you programmatically generate the first control, then you can copy the object to the needed locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you want to have labels that their text are same in your designer.

We make a class, say `LabelTextResourced`

```
public class LabelTextResourced: Label
{
    private string _textResourceName;
    public string TextResourceName
    {
        get { return _textResourceName; }
        set
        {
            _textResourceName = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textResourceName))
                base.Text = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(_textResourceName);
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set
        {
            // Set is done by resource name.
        }
    }
}
```

Build your project, now you can add `LabelTextResourced` control to your designer.

Right click your project and go to properties and select resource tab.
add a resource for example: `{Name: "LabelText", Value: "Hiiiiii!!!"}`

Now, go back to form designer, select your instance of `LabelTextResourced` and set it's `TextResourceName` property to `LabelText`.

Build again and now you should see that your label text is set from the resource. Now you can have many label that their text are all set from one location and changing the `LabelText` resource (and a build) results to changing of all of you `LabelTextResourced` controls that have `LabelText` as their `TextResourceName`.

This is just a starting point, you can customize this class and any other properties you want with some effort.

Comment: +1 for the creative answer. I have one question though: How would you update this during runtime...?

Comment: that is a whole new question, you can edit resource files in runtime but the changes wont reflects in your controls, I think supplying a method that get values from resource file again will solve the problem @Ric.Net

Answer (score 1):

You could set one of the control instance as a 'template' and copy all necessary properties to other instances (of course, leave there positions alone).

Answer (score 1):

As @nim suggested, you could create a property mapper. Of course, in design-time, things might look ugly. For example:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PropertyMapper.Map(txtBox1, textBox2, 
            new[] { "width", "font", "forecolor", "backcolor", "text" });
    }
}

public static class PropertyMapper
{
    public static void Map(Control source, Control target, params string[] properties)
    {
        properties = properties.Select(p => p.ToLowerInvariant()).ToArray();

        foreach (var prop in source.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => properties.Contains(p.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))
                .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite))
        {
            prop.SetValue(target, prop.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: and what's the solution in design time?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a static method to your form's code behind:

```
private static void SetTextToLabels(string text, params Label[] labels)
{
    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
        label.Text = text;
     }
}

// Use like this
private void UpdateTextInLabels()
{
    SetTextToLabels("SomeText", label1, label2, label3);
}
```

Or if all labels are in the same container (Form, Panel, etc.) and all labels in that container need to display the same you could write an extension method on the container control.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{    
    public static void SetTextOnMyLabels(this Control control, string text)
    {
        foreach (var label in control.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
             label.Text = text;
         }
     }
}

// Use like this in your form
private void UpdateTextInLabels()
{
    //Update all labels in panel1
    panel1.SetTextOnMyLabels("SomeText");
}
```

Comment: what's your solution in design time?

Comment: at design time my solution is simple: hold in the control button, select all labels you want to edit and changed their properties in the property window. VS is smart enough even with different controls in your selection to show only those properties that are common